# error: declaration shadows a local variable (mario.c)

Tags: cs50

Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Code and error below.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int blocks = 0;
    do 
    {
        printf("%d\n", blocks);
        int blocks = get_int();
    }
    while (blocks < 0 || blocks > 23);
}
```

mario.c:10:13: error: declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-Wshadow]
        int blocks = get_int();
            ^

mario.c:6:9: note: previous declaration is here
    int blocks = 0;
        ^

mario.c:10:13: error: unused variable 'blocks' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
        int blocks = get_int();
            ^

2 errors generated.

make: *** [mario] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are declaring  twice:

```
int blocks = 0;  //<--- First here
int blocks = get_int();  //<--- Then here
```

Try changing the second line to:

```
blocks = get_int();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to first say `int blocks = get_int()`
and then go to the

```
do
{
 printf....
}
```

my reasoning is that in your code you already gave `int blocks` a fixed integer, 0.

Right now i'm also stuck on this problem